Dead letter configuration in MassTransit
I am using MassTransit (8.0.16)
and using IReceiveEndpointConfigurator in order to configure it.
I have a fanout exchange which will send to it messages that cannot be currently handled (with TTL)
To that exchange I bind a topic exchange which bind to a direct exchange with a queue with a deadLetterExchange.
this will give me the ability to consume it again after the TTL.
In tests I use the InMemory but I could not figure out how to set the dead letter exchange
(IInmemoryReceieveEndpointConfiguratior.ConfigureDeadLetter ...)
Also, Is that possible to set exchange to exchange bind without any queue ?
Thanks a lot
I tried many options, but could not figure out how to do it.
